# What is the pythonic way to skip to the last element of a list in a for loop?

Tags: python, list

I would like to perform an operation to each element in my list, and when a certain condition is met, to skip to the last element of the list.

Here is a MWE where I print all the items in a list until I reach my condition (`item ==4`), after which I manually repeat the print statement on the final element. The desired output is to print 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7:

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
breaked_out = False
for item in my_list:
    print(item)
    if item == 4:
        breaked_out = True
        break
if breaked_out:
    print(my_list[-1])
```

I have this ugly use of a flag (`breaked_out`) and also need to repeat my `print()` command. This isn't particularly legible either.

I have a slightly better implementation in mind that uses a `while` loop instead:

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
i = 0
while i < len(my_list):
    item = my_list[i]
    print(item)

    if item == 4:
        i = len(my_list)-1
    else:
        i += 1
```

Here I'm not repeating my operation (in this case, `print()`) but I have to do this unpythonic index accounting.

Is there a more readable way to get this sort of iteration? Other things to add about my situation:

- This is iterating on a list, not a generator, so I have access to `len()`.
- I need to loop through in this order, so I can't `reverse(my_list)` and treat the special case first.

Comment: why cant you just replace `breaked_out = True` with `print(my_list[-1]` and remove the last if statement?

Comment: If the last value is 4, the first code might print it twice and the second code prints it infinitely. Which behaviour is correct?

Comment: I guess what I want it to do is print just once. But if it ran twice that would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There is no Pythonic way to do exactly what you want

#### Not what you asked for, but less ugly

The minimal change, not so ugly solution that doesn't actually advance the iterator is to just put the code in the loop instead of having a flag variable:

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

for item in my_list:
    print(item)
    if item == 4:
        print(my_list[-1])  # Handling of last element inlined
        break
# Optionally, an else: block can run to do something special when you didn't break
# which might be important if the item that's equal to 4 is the last or second
# to last item, where the former does the work for the final element twice,
# while the latter does it only once, but looks like it never found the element
# (processing all items without breaking looking the same as processing elements
# 0 through n - 1, then processing n separately, then breaking)
else:
    print("Processed them all!")
```

or to avoid processing the final element twice when it's the first element meeting the test criteria, use `enumerate` to track your position:

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

for i, item in enumerate(my_list, 1):  # Lets us test against len(my_list) rather than len(my_list) - 1
    print(item)
    if item == 4 and i < len(my_list):  # Don't process last item if we just processed it!
        print(my_list[-1])  # Handling of last element inlined
        break
```

#### What you asked for:

There's only two ways I know of to do this, both of which involve converting to an iterator first so you can manipulate the iterator within the loop so it will skip to the last element for the next loop. In both cases, your original code changes to:

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
lstiter = iter(my_list)
for item in lstiter:
    print(item)
    if item == 4:
        # iterator advance goes here
```

where that placeholder line at the bottom is what changes.

##### The documented, but slow approach

Using [the `consume` recipe from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), advance it to near the end. You need to know where you are, so the `for` loop changes to:

```
for i, item in enumerate(lstiter, 1):  # Starting from 1 avoids needing an extra - 1 in
                                       # the length check and consume's second argument
```

and the placeholder is filled with:

```
if i < len(my_list):
    consume(lstiter, len(my_list) - i)
```

Downside: Advancing an arbitrary iterator manually like this is `O(n)` (it has to produce and discard all the values, which can take time for a large `list`).

##### The efficient, but undocumented approach

`list` iterators provide a `__setstate__` method (it's used for `pickle`ing them so they can be unpickled at the same offset in the underlying `list`). You can abuse this to change the position of the iterator to any place you like. For this, you keep the `for` loop without `enumerate`, and just fill the placeholder with:

```
lstiter.__setstate__(len(my_list) - 1)
```

which directly skips to the iterator such that the next element it produces will be the final element of the `list`. It's efficient, it's simple, but it's non-obvious, and I doubt any part of the spec *requires* that `__setstate__` be provided at all, let alone implemented in this useful way (there are a bazillion methods you can choose from to implement pickling, and they could have selected another option). That said, the implementation is effectively required for all `pickle` protocol versions to date, for compatibility reasons (if they got rid of `__setstate__`, pickles produced on older Python would not be readable on modern Python), so it should be fairly reliable.

###### A warning:

If the final element of your `list` matches the condition, this will turn into an infinite loop, unlike the other solutions (`break` double processes the final element in that case, `consume` only processes each element at most once). `break`ing explicitly doesn't reenter the loop, so that's safe, and the `consume` recipe can't back up an iterator, so again, safe. But since this *sets* the position, it can set it back to the same position forever. If this is a possibility, I'd recommend the explicit `break` (using `enumerate` to check indices to avoid double-processing the final element), or failing that, you can add even more hackery by checking the length hint of the iterator to see if you were already at the end (and therefore should not adjust the position):

```
from operator import length_hint  # At top of file

my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
lstiter = iter(my_list)
for item in lstiter:
    print(item)
    if item == 4 and length_hint(lstiter) > 1:  # Don't set when finished or reaching last item anyway
        lstiter.__setstate__(len(my_list) - 1)
```

As an alternative to checking `length_hint` and similar hackery, you could use a flag variable that gets set to `True` when the condition passes and prevents reentering the `if` a second time, e.g.:

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
lstiter = iter(my_list)
skipped = False
for i, item in enumerate(lstiter, 1):
    print(item)
    if item == 4 and not skipped and i < len(my_list):  # Don't set when finished or reaching last item anyway
        lstiter.__setstate__(len(my_list) - 1)
        skipped = True
```

but this is straying further and further from Pythonic with every change. :-)

Comment: Like their originals, these might print a trailing 4 twice or infinitely instead of just once.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Yep. I was just fixing the efficient solution to avoid that; it won't adjust the iterator when it's already processing the final item. The `consume` version was already safe (neither doubles nor repeats infinitely). I left integrating `enumerate` into the `break`-based solution (to avoid doubling) as an exercise (there's multiple `enumerate` examples in here to base it on).

Comment: I guess we could alternatively check `lstiter.__length_hint__()`, but I can't tell whether that's more or less reliable than `lstiter.__setstate__` :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy: `__length_hint__` has no compatibility requirements, and it's allowed to lie. I can't see any reason why `list` iterators *would* (it would just deoptimize stuff), but it *could*. And it would only remove the need for `enumerate`, which is pretty low overhead anyway (we only test the `i` when the test succeeds anyway, so the cost is producing `i` at the C layer and unpacking the same `tuple` over and over, fairly trivial); nothing can replace `__setstate__` (because there is no publicly documented interface for setting the current position of an iterator; this ain't C++!).

Comment: And shoot, just realized `enumerate` solution doesn't work, because it's not actually advancing `enumerate` (so the index only goes up one). Maybe `__length_hint__` is the way to go. :-)

Comment: Hmm, maybe `enumerate` is low overhead compared to `print`, but it's [pretty significant](https://tio.run/##hY/BasMwEETv@oo52kEU2W6gBPwlIQiZ7FLRSBZrBZyvd6S4EHrqHGd23u6mR/6e4/CVZNtY5oDsA/kMH9IsGUKJXFbqSgzumnVpTwpFPAtW@Ih12Y0qz8UbR3y@rapJyP38Ivq/CK93CsV7IHGZ3vH/wHXBiLPR6DR6jeGCA/qjscYYpSqdK/rMJea@hsOOyaUWfGz235qbC9PVncB1t0a5ZCIZu7Z9DSfxMTf8YW10gazVpX5AR0O7bU8) compared to the rest.

Comment: Yet another way would be to [split the list](https://tio.run/##RYzLCoMwFET3@YpZKlyhqfaB4JeIlLZEemlexGz8@tRUbWc3hznj5/hytr76kNIYnAFHFaJzegIb70IET5qfSggz3zRPER36A0ESjoSa0BBOhDPhMggxupAPzCLbTSw2j6CV3UtZyZKwlb6S7dAKLNn9r55/VpzjA9tYZFj@GI/ruuvQ/Jc5j6Du75Q@) into two phases right away, but I don't really like it...

Comment: @KellyBundy: Sure, but that's all relative (and pretty small in practice for real work). `enumerate` just barely more than doubles the overhead. Given that it's operating on a `list` of existing values (that should have almost no overhead at all to produce), having it manually produce sequential Python `int`s, pack them in a `tuple`, then have the bytecode interpreter unpack them, it's adding surprisingly little (partially because, when you unpack, it can cheat and reuse the *same* `tuple` for every result). *shrugs*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247692/discussion-between-shadowranger-and-kelly-bundy).

Comment: I think what I had in mind all along was something like `consume`. I looked for it in itertools but didn't find it. (I didn't realize there existed a more-itertools package! :o)

Comment: I'm not super worried about the warning. What the `print` function represents is something that changes state. The condition also depends on the state. It would be pretty remarkable for both to lock in such a way to give me an infinite loop :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do too much for a simple task

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for item in my_list:
    print(item)
    if item == 4:
        print(my_list[-1])
        break
    # task here
```